# how to find and delete selected row in dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have a dataGridView on my form.
also i have a button that i want delete selected row in dataGridView by click on it.
but i have several tables in my sql file that each one may loaded in dataGridView on my form.
how to find which table showed in dataGridView until delete selected row on it.
excuse me, my english is not good.
thanks....

Comment: Instead of trying to "find" which table is loaded into the datagrid view it probably would be easier to just keep track of that as you load the tables in.  You can then just get the selection properties you need to figure out which row to delete and should be fairly straightforward from there.

Comment: you can figure out which table is loaded using table column names(check your dataGrid column names)

Comment: can you help me with your codes?